# Unable to validate the following destination configurations within CloudFormation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

Hey I'm trying to connect my S3 bucket to my SQS queue so that whenever an item is put in the bucket, it triggers the SQS to send a message, but whenever I input my json file into CloudFormation I get the error message when creating the InputBucket of:

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: DFD145B5BE09259A; S3 Extended Request ID: NCSQdpnfd0J35vVU1BKwO7PSyLbaQ3GxyVmJ0mr/eTMlxRgrGnzmUC/wCn7Q5x4rKtSFF+mxNjc=)
```

My current json is:

```
    "Resources": {
    "SQSQueue": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    },
    "InputBucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "DependsOn": ["SQSQueue"],
        "Properties": {
            "NotificationConfiguration": {
                "QueueConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
                        "Queue": {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "SQSQueue", "Arn" ]}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "AccessControl": "PublicRead"
        }

    }
}
```

}

Can anyone spot whats wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, you should consider a couple of things: 1. use YAML rather than JSON (it's better in many ways) and 2. use s3:ObjectCreated:* rather than s3:ObjectCreated:Put (because you probably want to trigger on any kind of upload to S3).

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this article [How do I avoid the error "Unable to validate the following destination configurations" when using S3 event notifications in AWS CloudFormation?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/)